# Why OracleConnection isn't returned to the pool?

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection, ojdbc

I have a problem which I did not find on the Internet.

I'm trying to connect to DB with ojdbc6. I get resource from jndi

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ds_conn" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="10" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@someDB.com:1731/nameDB" 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true; 
oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT=5000;" password="pass" username="user"
maxWait="10000" maxIdle="300" maxActive="1000" auth="Container"/>
```

with the method

```
public OracleConnection getConnection() throws OracleDatabaseReaderConnectionException, NamingException {

    Context initialContext = null;
    try {
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ds_conn");
        OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        return connection;
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new OracleDatabaseReaderConnectionException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (initialContext != null) {
            initialContext.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

and next I'm executing query

```
try (OracleConnection connection = getConnection();
    OraclePreparedStatement preparedStatement = (OraclePreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        OracleResultSet resultSet = (OracleResultSet) preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

    //some actions

} catch (OracleDatabaseReaderConnectionException | SQLException | NamingException e) {
        throw new OracleDatabaseReaderException(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

As I understand it's a usual actions to connect to db and execute the query.

But connection doesn't close. As you can see in my jndi I have param maxTotal="10". So after 10 queries pool is becoming full and other queries just waiting for a place in pool. I dont know how to resolve this problem and make connections closed. Maybe I have conflict in casting Connection to OracleConnection and so on? Maybe thy-with-resources doesn't work well?

Comment: `try-with-resources` just calls `connection.close()` at the end. It works just fine.

Comment: have you encounter with any error or exception ? if yes then please share

Comment: @Afgan, unfortunately there are no any exceptions. New connections are waiting endlessly without exceptions

Comment: As per your code i haven't seen anywhere you have close connection or not

Comment: @Afgan, I use try-with-resoures (3rd code example). it closes on its own after block try.

Comment: Sorry, missed the bug 'cos it was all the way on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're closing the inner `OracleConnection` instead of the outer wrapper. The difference being that the former **really** closes the connection, whereas closing the wrapper will just return the connection to the pool.

```
(OracleConnection) dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Here calling `unwrap()` causes the pooling wrapper to disappear, and you can't call `close` on it anymore. One way fix this would be to call `unwrap()` only after starting a `try-with-resources`, like this:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {  // Now the pooled connection will be "closed"
    OracleConnection oc = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

    try(OraclePreparedStatement ps ...) ...
```

But that's not very pretty, at least if you need to do it in lots of places. Is it absolutely necessary to use the Oracle specific classes instead of the JDBC interfaces here?

Comment: Nice answer, tnx. It is absolutely necessary to use OraclePreparedStatement. I need for methods preparedStatement.setStringAtName(..) and preparedStatement.setNullAtName(..) and so on.

Comment: @Adey if you're using those for CLOB purposes, I'd be surprised if you couldn't work around that somehow. However if you don't do that everywhere, it doesn't really matter.